# Batch file invoked file details

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I invoke a batch file from my own extension file type.In batch file i will show the details of invoking file.  I know by passing parameters when invokation we will pass it and we will get by "%~sn1" OR "%1" OR "%~nx1". But i need without passing parameters.

```
Sample Example
My batch file code looks like this(main.bat)

@ECHO on
set modelname=(here i want help) 
java  -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" -Xms1024m  -Xmx1024m -jar  dist/XYZ.jar -models %modelname%
exit
```

If i click "**Kitchen.xyz**" then it'll invoke my batch file "***main.bat***". Now i want set "***modelname***" as "***Kitchen.xyz***". If i click "***LivingRoom.xyz***" ,:***modelname***" set as "***LivingRoom.xyz***".

Can anyone help please...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the Windows Registry associated with the file type of .xyz

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xyz\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xyz\shell\Name Of Your Command]
@="&Name Of Your Command"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xyz\shell\Name Of Your Command\command]
@="\"C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Batch\\File\\main.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Save that text in a .reg file and execute it to apply the registry changes.  Then when you right click .xyz files, "Name Of Your Command" will be one of the options and possibly the default option which would run when double clicked.

Then your main.bat still needs to accept one parameter and assign it to modelname.

You could also do that programatically with the `REG` command, but regardless of which method you use to set things up, something needs to be run to setup each machine you want to do this on.

Comment: Also note that if your .xyz is some system extension, there are other areas in the registry that control their execution.

Comment: Thanks @Cookie Butter. Your answer set parameter %1" in the registry. It's look sending parameter. Is it possible to fetch without sending parameters?

Comment: Maybe, but at some point your script needs to know the filename it should be processing, so the easiest and most straightforward way is with a parameter.  Is there a reason you don't want the filename as a parameter?

Comment: Agree.. i work with registry and it's works .Thanks @CookieButter